# Aysnc validator angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms

I am tryin to check username availablity on typing username using a rest api. I am using angular forms for validators. From backend I get true is username exists and false if not. I am using below code :

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            userName: ['', [Validators.required, this.userNameValidator.bind(this)]],
        });

userNameValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        return this.adminService.checkUserName(control.value).subscribe((Response:any)=>{
            return Response._body ? true : {'invalidUserName': true};
        })
    }, 1000);}
```

Its showing null in errors property of form control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code.

1. You never actually return anything from the `userNameValidator` method, you should return an observable (or promise).
2. You should not use `setTimeOut`, instead use `timer` from the RxJs library as this returns an observable.
3. Use switchMap on the timer result to return your observable from your async call
4. You should return a result using `map` and not subscribe, the controls validation will subscribe to the returned observable.
5. If validation passes you should return `null`

```
import { ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

userNameValidator(control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return timer(1000).pipe(switchMap(() => {
        return this.adminService.checkUserName(control.value).pipe(map((Response:any)=>{
            return Response._body ? null : {'invalidUserName': true};
        }));
    }));
}
```